# CUFFT_ALLOC_FAILED Error in nsight eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, gpu

I wrote a simple cuda file that successfully build in visual studio 2010 & nsight eclipse

the code is here

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <cufft.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>

typedef float2 Complex; 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
     const int NX = 1024;

 const int BATCH = 90000;

     const int SIGNAL_SIZE = NX * BATCH;

     Complex* h_signal = (Complex*)malloc(sizeof(Complex) * SIGNAL_SIZE);

     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_SIZE; ++i) {
    h_signal[i].x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    h_signal[i].y = 0;
}

Complex* d_signal;
cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_signal, sizeof(Complex)*SIGNAL_SIZE));


cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_signal, h_signal, sizeof(Complex)*SIGNAL_SIZE,
                          cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

cufftHandle plan;
cufftSafeCall(cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH));


cufftSafeCall(cufftExecC2C(plan, (cufftComplex *)d_signal, (cufftComplex *)d_signal,   CUFFT_FORWARD));

cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(h_signal, d_signal, SIGNAL_SIZE*sizeof(Complex),
                          cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

//Destroy CUFFT context
cufftSafeCall(cufftDestroy(plan));

// cleanup memory
free(h_signal);
cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(d_signal));

cudaThreadExit();

 cutilExit(argc, argv);
}
```

I changed NX & BATCH four times for example with

```
const int NX = 1024;

const int BATCH = 90000;

const int SIGNAL_SIZE = NX * BATCH;

cufftHandle plan;
cufftPlan1d(&plan, NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH);
```

I successfully run Sample in visual studio 2010 & 2012 (windows 7 64 bit) but in ubuntu
12.04 (32 bit) nsight eclipse give this Error

CUFFT_ALLOC_FAILED

for cufftPlan1d function

I change BATCH to 80000 (NX = 1024) & this error occurred in ubuntu
but in visual studio 2010 i run without any errors!

I use Cuda toolkit 5.5 that has this feature:

Transform sizes up to 128 million elements in single precision

and 80000 * 1024 = 81920000 elements < 128 million elements

I change BATCH to 8000 (NX = 1024) & that error does not occured in ubuntu

Please Help Me

thanks

Comment: When and where does the error occur?

Comment: Note that `cudaThreadExit()` has been deprecated in favour of `cudaDeviceReset()`, see [this document](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__THREAD__DEPRECATED_gf423ba04af587d42b52799455a7c094d.html)

Comment: I have a GTX 650 Ti boost that has 2 GB RAM. I build and run samples in same machine (first in windows 7 & visual studio 2010 then in ubuntu 12.04) when i set Nx = 1024 & Batch = 90000 nsight eclipse has an CUFFT_ALLOC_FAILED error but in visual studio i run it without any errors!

Answer (score 3):

You can estimate the amount of memory required by your cuFFT call using `cufftEstimate1d`.

```
#include <conio.h>

#include <cufft.h>

#define cufftSafeCall(err)      __cufftSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)
inline void __cufftSafeCall(cufftResult err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if( CUFFT_SUCCESS != err) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cufftSafeCall() CUFFT error in file <%s>, line %i.\n",
        file, line);
    getch(); exit(-1);
    }
}


int main() {

    const int NX = 1024;

    const int BATCH = 100000;

    size_t workSize;

    cufftSafeCall(cufftEstimate1d(NX, CUFFT_C2C, BATCH, &workSize));

    printf("%i\n",workSize);

    getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

CUFFT Documentation: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/#function-cufftplan1d

`CUFFT_ALLOC_FAILED : The allocation of GPU resources for the plan failed.`

Meaning `cufftPlan1d()` was not able to allocate memory on the GPU, likely because there is not enough free memory. The available VRAM would not have changed between operating systems, so either you don't have the right drivers for your card or you're running Ubuntu on a separate machine with a GPU that has limited VRAM. You can check the available global memory with `cudaGetDeviceProperties()`

Comment: i used same machine. i think the driver doesn't have a problem because all cuda samples build and run successfully!

Comment: i think gpu allocation differs in 32 bit and 64 bit is this true?